# Why is the "trilogy" made of five books?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

I just completed the first book in the Hitchhiker's Guide series and started the second. Something I've seen written about the series is that it is a "trilogy of five", which taken literally is an oxymoron. Is there a reason why this label has been used? Was it intentional whimsy, or did "trilogy" just not for some reason get corrected when the later books appeared?

Comment: I don't know why everybody keeps going on about HHGG. There are so many trilogies consisting of more than three books. Dune, Dragonlance etc. There's even one I know of that consists of only two books: Larry Niven's Smoke Ring trilogy.

Comment: That may well be, but I haven't read any of those, so I didn't know about the "trilogy" business. I have been reading HHGG, which inspired the question.

Comment: @MrLister - Star Wars :)

Comment: I took it as a joke.

Comment: Robert Rankin has the Brentford trilogy with 8 total...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Obstensibly, Adams finished the books at Three, but later came back.

> The novels are described as "*a trilogy in five parts*", having been described as a trilogy on the release of the third book, and then a "*trilogy in four parts*" on the release of the fourth book. The US edition of the fifth book was originally released with the legend "*The fifth book in the increasingly inaccurately named Hitchhiker's Trilogy*" on the cover. Subsequent re-releases of the other novels bore the legend "*The [first, second, third, fourth] book in the increasingly inaccurately named Hitchhiker's Trilogy*". In addition, the blurb on the fifth book humorously describes the book as "*the book that gives a whole new meaning to the word 'trilogy'*".
>   ~[Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Novels)

It was a tongue in cheek way of describing the books, without going back on a previous statement, and fits very well with some of the nonsensical themes in the book.

Answer (score 13):

[@Pureferret](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48890/2760) has the right answer but the question is wrong.

For THHGTTG's 30<sup>th</sup> anniversary, part six of three, [And Another Thing...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Another_Thing..._(novel)) was published. This book was written by [Eoin Colfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eoin_Colfer) since Adams was unavailable to write the book due to his being dead for biological reasons.

[image: Book cover]

The name of the book is taken from *So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish*:

> The storm had now definitely abated, and what thunder there was now grumbled over more distant hills, like a man saying '**And another thing...**' twenty minutes after admitting he's lost the argument.

Comment: Instead of "answering" the question with this non-answer, why didn't you either comment on the question, or just submit an edit to it to correct it?

Comment: This answer is funnier than a comment would have been, I’m firmly in favour.

Comment: Objections? Overruled!

Comment: +1 for "being dead for biological reasons."  I feel like he would have approved of that description.

Comment: @DaveJohnson or, as slartibartfast could have said, Douglas Adams is just (another time) very late ... as in: "the late Douglas Adams".

Comment: @phantom42 a play on the answer to the meaning of life in book 1, that they had the answer to the wrong question, I'm guessing ;)